Why is semantic consequence usually referred as real truth preserving compared to syntactic consequence?
I am new to logic and I try to do my best to understand by myself but this part is very confusing to me.
I read here and in many other places that semantic consequence is used to know if a proposition is actually true, and that soundness is required to know if the rules of inference of a system are actually truth preserving. Aren't the rules of inference truth preserving by definition ?

We want that they are truth preserving and we prove that our "preferred" ones, like e.g. Modus Ponens, are so.


Aren't the rules of inference truth preserving by definition?

No, not in the sense that being truth-preserving w.r.t. some semantics is a definitional requirement. On its own, a syntactic rule system it is just a bunch of instructions for manipulating symbols, and in principle you could make up whatever rules you like. For example, a system consisting of two rules "From $A$ derive $A \land B$" and "From $A \land B$" derive $B$" is perfectly well-defined as far as the bare notion of syntactic consequence is concerned.
Of course, if the system is to be useful, it should be sound (and ideally also complete) w.r.t. a preferred notion of semantic consequence. But that a particular system indeed has this property is by no means the case automatically, and has to be proved by verifying that each of the rules ends up doing what we want them to do.
For the example above we can see that this is not the case because the first rule gives rise to a non-truth-preserving consequence. But the point is that this does not follow just from the fact that it is a syntactic system. Here I chose a simple and obviously nonsensical set of rules on purpose, but it is quite conceivable that a new syntactic system intended to capture a certain semantic consequence relation turns out to actually fail at this.

This answer is misleading. The orthodox view requires inference rules to be truth-preserving.

I guess one can debate whether the term "syntactic rule system" is more commonly understood to have the property of soundness already included on top of its literal meaning as "a set of rules for manipulating strings of symbols", but my point was that when has such a system in the sense of the latter one still has to prove that it also qualifies as the former. If there was no concept of a syntactic system without truth-preservance already baked in, then the term "soundness" would be meaningless.

Imo saying that we want what we call inference rules to be truth-preserving does not really help answer the OP's question. There obviously is a distinction to be made between syntactic systems that are truth-preserving and ones which are not, even if you prefer not to call them inference rules, and the non-obviousness is what this question is about.

@NatalieClarius After some research I just understood that truth preserving is actually a chosen property of a rule. Then another question arises, in a truth table, I can easily see how to complete the output with the rules of inference when the output is true, that is by finding a sequence of rules that brings up the conclusion, but how does one come up with a false conclusion? Do we have to prove that there is no proof whatsoever to bring up truth from the specific truth assignment of the premises?

Not sure I understand your question. Truth preserving means that under every valuation (= row in the truth table) under which all of the premises are true, the conclusion is true as well, or conversely, for each valuation, if the conclusion is false then at least one of the premises must be false too. The first of the rules I made up violates this because with A true and B false there exists a row where the premise (A) is true but the conclusion (A ^ B) is false, hence this rule is unsound.

@NatalieClarius Yes I do understand that, but how do we complete a truth table using the rules of inference?

I don't think you understand. We don't fill the truth table using the rules of inference. Instead we check each rule for soundness by completing the truth table in the usual way for the formulas occurring in the rule and checking whether the semantic consequence relation holds between the premises and the conclusion.

But who decided how were the truth table filled? Who decided if depending on the truth values of the premises the conclusion is true or false if it isn't from the rules? Thank you very much for your time.

The truth functionns of the logical operators, as usual. Filling in a truth table is entirely determined by semantics. That's the whole point of soundness: We compare the syntactic consequence relation as given by the rules against the semantic consequence relation as given by the truth table.

And how can we know if the semantics we choose are correct ?

What would it mean for a semantics to be "correct"? Correct with respect to what? We can compare whether a syntactic consequence system behaves in accordance with a prior notion of semantic consequence, which we then call correctness. But semantics means meaning and thus itself is already the basis of our understanding of inference. There is nothing to compare it against to judge correctness. We can perhaps test the formal semantics against some intuitions of what consequences we expect to hold, but there is nothing to be objectively correct.

So why do we say that mathematics are exact if the logic system we use is chosen because of some properties based on intuition ?

This is a different question best to be asked in a new post and becoming rather out of scope for this thread.

Not an answer, but I wish to draw attention to some follow-up points an explanation of which, I hope, may be helpful for the interested:

In any book that presents the fundamentals of logical model theory, we see such definitions as the following (here, the source is Chang and Keisler's Model Theory; the bold font added):


1.3.15. Suppose that $\varphi$ is a formula of $\mathscr{L}$ and all free and bound variables of $\varphi$ are among $v_{0},\ldots, v_{q}$.
(i). If $\varphi$ is $\theta_{1}\wedge\theta_{2}$, then
$\mathfrak{A}\vDash\varphi[x_{0}\ldots x_{q}]$ if and only if both
$\mathfrak{A}\vDash\theta_{1}[v_{0}\ldots v_{q}]$ and
$\mathfrak{A}\vDash\theta_{2}[v_{0}\ldots v_{q}]$.
(ii). If $\varphi$ is $\neg\theta$, then
$\mathfrak{A}\vDash\varphi[v_{0}\ldots v_{q}]$ if and only if not
$\mathfrak{A}\vDash\theta_{2}[v_{0}\ldots, v_{q}]$.

Likewise, this is from Boxes and Diamonds: An Open Introduction to Modal Logic by the Open Logic Project (the bold font added):


$A\equiv (B\wedge C)$: $M,w\Vdash A$ iff $M,w\Vdash B$ and $M,w\Vdash C$.
$A\equiv (B\vee C)$: $M,w\Vdash A$ iff $M,w\Vdash B$ or $M,w\Vdash C$ (or both).


When we focus on the bold font words, the question suggests itself: Isn't it circular to give the semantic interpretation of $\wedge, \vee, \neg$ with the words and, or, not, respectively? If not circular, what could their difference be?

Consider the rule of modens of ponens:

$$\dfrac{A\qquad A\rightarrow B}{B}$$
Could we find a semantic interpretation that would invalidate this rule? Or, do we ever arrange the arguments each time to confirm it?

Yes that is also a point i'd appreciate explanation on, thank you for bringing that up.

We want that they are sound, i.e. truth preserving and we prove that our preferred ones, like e.g. Modus Ponens, are so.
See Rule of inference: "In logic and the philosophy of logic, specifically in deductive reasoning, a rule of inference, inference rule or transformation rule is a logical form consisting of a function which takes premises, analyzes their syntax, and returns a conclusion (or conclusions). Typically, a rule of inference preserves truth, a semantic property."
